# gitolite not creating repos with subconf

Tags: git, gitolite

Edited and pushed the the following configuration files:

file: `gitolite-admin\conf\gitolite.conf`with the content:

```
subconf %HOSTNAME "%HOSTNAME/*.conf"
repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   useradmin
    option mirror.master = server1
    option mirror.slaves = server2 server3
```

and the files

```
gitolite-admin\conf\server1\server1.conf
gitolite-admin\conf\server2\server2.conf
gitolite-admin\conf\server3\server3.conf
```

with the content of

```
repo test1
    RW+     =   adminuser
```

when pushing I get the following and the repo is not created in none of the servers

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: WARNING: subconf 'server1' attempting to set access for test1
To git@10.12.42.12:gitolite-admin
   d25ffe1..186ba79  master -> master
Done
```

**edit**
running gitolite3 v3.1-8-ga509b20 on git 1.7.9.5